# How can I match a new line after N times for a specific char?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match all the new lines on a CSV-like file. The problem is that huge file always comes with some broken lines, for example:

```
123|some string field|person 123|some optional open comment|324|213
133|some string field|person||324|213
153|some string field|person 123|some comment|324|213
126|some string field|another id|some open and
new line comment|324|213
153|string field|person 123|some comment|324|213
153|string field|person 123|another broken line
comment|324|213
133|field|person||324|213
```

So, to solve this cases I've used the following logic:

```
    string ZSUR = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    string originalFilePath = filePath;

    // Regular Expression to fix line break issues
    Regex RE = new Regex(@"[\r\t\n]+([^0-9\r\t\n]{3}[^|\r\t\n])");

    ZSUR = RE.Replace(ZSUR, "$1");

    // Backup the original file
    string[] backupFilePath = Regex.Split(filePath, @".txt$");
    File.Delete(backupFilePath[0] + "_BACKUP.txt");
    File.Move(originalFilePath, backupFilePath[0] + "_BACKUP.txt");

    // And then save on the same path the fixed file
    File.WriteAllText(originalFilePath, ZSUR);
```

It's solved 90% of the cases, because the first part of correct lines always starts with a three digit number followed by a pipe.

But I don't know why its don't matches with cases like this:

```
126|some string field|another id|some open and
double newlined 
123 coment|324|213
153|some string field|person 123|some comment|324|213
153|some string field|person 123|some comment|324|213
153|string field|person 123|Please split this line
31 pcs: 05/03/2013
31|324|213
153|some string field|person 123|some comment|324|213
```

As you can see, I need a diferent approach to solve this.
I know that after N times I've a pipe, that annoying comment field is there.
So, there's some way to match all new lines and similars after N pipes from the start of a line ?

Others ideas are welcome too.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers guys.

I solved this using the following regex:

```
(?<!\|[CA]?\|([0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4})?)[\n\r]+
```

Of course, my real file is slight different from the posted example, but the main ideia is just to match all new lines [\n\r]+ that doesn't preceded by the

```
(?<! ... )
```

expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first replace all (\|\d+\n) with something weird like \|\d~~

then join all lines, removing \n

then split by ~~

Answer (score 1):

You could process everything like so where "Clean" is a method you define.

```
var prev = string.Empty;
const int requiredValueCount = 6;

foreach (var line in lines2.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    var values = (prev + line).Split('|');

    if (values.Length == requiredValueCount)
    {
        prev = string.Empty;
        Clean(values);
    }
    else
    {
        prev += line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel unneccesarily. Try Sebastien Lorion's [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). It may well do what you need to do (or provide the facilities for you to take corrective action on errors). I've used this reader and its quite good.

Another option is [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/releases/view/101259) from Codeplex. Never used it, but it might be good.

I'd also take the approach of reading the file as-is into a list of records. Since it doesn't seem that you need more than a single bit of lookahead/lookbehind, you could do it pretty easily in a single pass of the file, something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> ReadRecordsFromCSV()
{
  string[] prev = null ;
  string[] curr = null ;

  // read each individual record from the file
  while ( null != (curr=MyCsvReader.ReadRecord()) )
  {

    if ( prev == null )
    { // no previous record? just shift and continue
      prev = curr ;
    }
    else
    { // previous record? splice if needed and emit a record
      string[] record ;
      bool spliceNeeded = CheckForSpliceConditions(prev,curr) ;

      if ( spliceNeeded )
      { // splice needed? build the record to emit and clear the previous record
        record = Splice( prev , curr ) ;
        prev = null ;
      }
      else
      { // no splice needed? set the record to emit and shift
        record = prev ;
        prev = curr ;
      }

    }

    // emit the record
    yield return record ;
  }

  // emit the last record if there is one.
  if ( prev != null )
  {
    yield return prev ;
  }

}
```

If you need more than one level of lookahead/lookbehind, you need something like a shift register, where you add records to the end of the list and remove them from the beginning of the list. You could use a `List<string[]>` as such a shift register, though it's a little ugly to do so.

**Edited to note:** Alternatively (and simpler), if a splice is needed, just append the current record to the previous record until a splice is no longer needed. Once that's true, the previous record gets emitted and you start over with a clean slate, thus:

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> ReadRecordsFromCSV()
{
  string[] prev = null ;
  string[] curr = null ;

  // read each individual record from the file
  while ( null != (curr=MyCsvReader.ReadRecord()) )
  {

    if ( prev == null )
    { // no previous record? just shift and continue
      prev = curr ;
    }
    else
    { // previous record? splice if needed and emit a record
      bool spliceNeeded = CheckForSpliceConditions(prev,curr) ;

      if ( spliceNeeded )
      { // splice needed? build the record to emit and clear the previous record
        prev = Splice( prev , curr ) ;
      }
      else
      { // no splice needed? set the record to emit and shift
        yield return prev ;
        prev = null ;
      }

    }

  }

  // emit the last record if there is one.
  if ( prev != null )
  {
    yield return prev ;
  }

}
```